# Proof: if $n > 1$ then $LD(n) $ is a prime number

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification

I've endeavored to teach myself more math $20$ years out of school, and I'm starting with a book called Haskell Road to Maths, Logic, and Programming, which was recommended as a good way to learn proofs (and I'm a programmer).

One of the very first problems involves the proposition in the title:

If $n >$ 1 then $LD(n)$ is a prime number

where $LD(n)$ is the least natural number greater than $1$ that divides $n$.

It then describes a "proof by contradiction" in such a way that I cannot even begin to understand it even after a half dozen readings, and after working through all the related problems.  The book is supposed to teach proofs in later chapters, but I'd like to understand everything in this chapter before moving on.

Can someone please describe a/the proof by contradiction for this proposition in easy language that a beginner in proof writing could understand?

Comment: Your question is not self-contained.  Only someone with access to the book will have any idea what LD(n) is supposed to mean.  Can you provide more detail?  Do you have a URL for the book?

Comment: probably it is least divisor?

Comment: Apologies, it's "Least Divisor".  I had assumed this was standard notation since the book never defined the abbreviation, but it was used in the context of prime number searching, so I figured it out.  The book has no online edition available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a=LD(n)$. For the sake of contradiction assume that $a$ is not prime. Then by definition we have $a=bc$ for some $b,c \in \mathbb{N}$ and neither $b$ nor $c$ are equal to one. Then $b<a$ and $b$ divides $n$. But this contradicts the minimality of $a$. Thus $a$ is prime.

Comment: How does b divide n?   And what is the "minimality of a"?  Do I need to ask separate questions for this?

Comment: Is there a good book you'd recommend for these basics?  Perhaps I lack the base to start where I'm starting.  Nonetheless, I'm actually understanding the applications/code part of this book with no problems, it's just the proofs I'm struggling with.

Comment: b divides n, because a divides n and b divides a. By definition a is the smallest natural number which divides n. But we found another natural number which is smaller than a and divides n. This is a contradiction.

Comment: i think the best way to get better at proofs is to do as many as you can by yourself and also read proofs from other people who are really good at writing proofs.

Comment: Many thanks for your comments, I understand the proof now.  Also thanks for your advice, I'll just continue doing proofs and see how things go.